# How to quickly switch from bracketed to single shot shooting?

Tags: olympus, camera-controls, olympus-omd

I frequently switch between exposure bracketing and single shot shooting, and this is kind of a pain because I have to change two settings. For example, let's say I want to bracket 3 exposures with a 0.3ev difference between them. I have to do two things from the menu:

- set the exposure bracketing to on, and select the 3 x 0.3 option
- set the frame advance rate to high (H)

The frame advance is important because all three exposures need to be closely aligned to construct a composite image. When the frame advance rate is set to high in conjunction with the bracketing being on, then the camera will automatically shoot the bracket as fast as it can as shoon as the shutter release is pressed.

The problem is that I often will go back and forth betwen making single exposures and bracketed exposures. Is there any way to automate the settings change so I can do this switchover faster?

I am currently using an OM-D M1 II, and a Pen-F. Both cameras have similar menu setting options.

Comment: Set the OM-D with bracketing on. Set the Pen-F with bracketing off. Or vice versa?

Comment: Why do you need to turn off high rate frame advance to take single shots? You just need to be fast enough letting the shutter button up with your finger.

Comment: Do your Olys have any pre-programmed "Custom User" modes? Where you set the camera up the way you want and "save" that profile to a "Custom Profile" that you can instantly call up later? That's how I often switch multiple settings with one control movement on my Canon bodies.

Answer (score 1):

Following up from Michael Clark's comment, the solution is to use "custom modes". All the settings of the camera can be saved to one of four profiles or "mysets" designated C1, C2, C3 and C4. The steps to do this are:

1. Set the camera to a desired configuration.
2. Go to menu Picture1 / Reset/Assign Custom Modes
3. Select one of the four choices C1, C2, C3 or C4
4. Press 'OK' on Set

The camera settings, including bracketing and frame advance, are saved to the mode.

You can then put the camera into that configuration by using the mode dial (the one that says "P A S M C1 C2 C3 C4").

The main disadvantage of this is that all of the other settings are changed too. So, the white balance may need to be adjusted and possibly exposure settings as well. However, if you are on a shooting sprint, then in many cases the exposure setting will be the same, so the custom modes just need to be adjusted appropriately before you begin. For example, if you are shooting outdoor scenes in daylight, then go to C1, change to daylight, Picture1/Assign C1 set, then repeat for the other three modes. Then your modes are set for the rest of the day.